# csh script with command line options

Tags: shell, csh

I am currently writing a script in csh and my script has to take a `-f` command line option so my script would look like this:

```
checker -f
```

and that would do what I would want it to do.
How would I check if if the user put a `-f` command line option?

```
if($1 == "-f") then
    do something
endif
```

This above gives me the error saying "if: Missing file name". I'm pretty sure I'm going the wrong way about check to see if the user is putting a command line option — but what should I be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enclose `$1` in double quotation marks `"` for this to work:

```
#!/bin/csh   
if ("$1" == "-f") then
    echo RIGHT FLAG
else
    echo WRONG OR NO FLAG
endif
```

which yields:

```
% ./c.sh -f
RIGHT FLAG
% ./c.sh -z
WRONG OR NO FLAG
% ./c.sh
WRONG OR NO FLAG
```

One alternative way to achieve the same is to prepend a *dummy character*, like `b` or whatever, to *both* parts of the `==` expression, like this:

```
if (b$1 == b-f) then
```

---

The reason why this happens is related to a rather arcane combination of some, seemingly unrelated, factors:

- First, you chose your command line switch to be called `f`
- Second, the expression `if($1 == "-f")` is evaluated as `if (-f == -f)`.
- Third, `-f` is part of a `csh` *file enquiry* scheme when used with an expression like `if ( == )`.

The above combination is interpreted by `csh` as an attempt to use the `-f` operator on a file named literally `==`, which, of course, is non-existent hence the "if: Missing file name".

The following is a list of csh's file enquiry switches:

```
r, w, x, e, o, z, f, d
```

Had you chosen any letter not present on this list, you wouldn't have encountered your problem :

```
if($1 == "-a") then
    echo OK
endif
```

results to:

```
% ./c.sh -a
OK
%
```